# difficulty rendering gganimate map

Tags: r, gganimate

I'm new to `gganimate`. Great package.

I'm able to reproduce the package examples, but I'm struggling to render my actual use cases. I wonder if any `gganimate` users would be willing to determine if there is more efficient way to run this code. I've tried on my local machine and on RStudio Cloud. I've also tried plotting weekly data rather than daily data (so reducing the overall data by 6/7.

```
# load packages 
  library(tidyverse)
  library(sf)
  library(viridis)
  library("rio")

# get county geometry
  url <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ericpgreen/717596c37478ef894c14b250477fae92/raw/c2cf4b273a2c7f0677f22a37b5e9f7e893204e3b/cali.R"
  cali <- rio::import(url)

# get covid data
  covid <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# prep covid data
  covidPrepped <-
  covid %>%
  filter(state=="California") %>%
  select(date, fips, cases, deaths) %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date)) %>%
  mutate(fips = stringr::str_pad(fips, width=5, pad="0")) 

# make sure every county has a row for every day
  complete <- 
  cali %>%
  left_join(covidPrepped, by = c("GEOID" = "fips")) %>%
  complete(GEOID, date, fill = list(cases = 0)) %>%
  select(date, GEOID, cases)

# join back to geometry and construct casesPop
  pData <- 
  complete %>%
  left_join(select(cali, GEOID, NAME, estimate, geometry),
            by = "GEOID") %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(casesPop = (cases/estimate)*100000) %>%
  mutate(casesPop = ifelse(is.na(casesPop), 0, casesPop)) %>%
  mutate(group = cut(casesPop, 
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 
                                300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 
                                Inf),
                     labels = c(0, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 
                                300, 1000, 3000, 10000),
                     include.lowest = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date, 
                                  label=TRUE, 
                                  abbr=TRUE),
         day = lubridate::day(date),
         monthDay = paste(month, day, sep=" ")) %>%
  select(GEOID, geometry, group, monthDay) 

# animate
  ggplot(pData) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = group), color = "white", size=.1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "magma", drop=FALSE) +

  coord_sf(crs = 102003) +
  # on RStudio Cloud I got a CRS error with the line above
  # switching to the line below works
  #coord_sf(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80", datum=NA) + 

  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.justification='left') +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +

# gganimate portion
  transition_states(monthDay,
                    transition_length = 4,
                    state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')
```

Comment: You are rendering about 100 ggplot maps, so this takes a while, but after 3.3 minutes on my machine it finished rendering this: https://i.imgur.com/GxA0aFW.gifv. Maybe once some parallel routines find their way into `gganimate`, things could be faster, but they do work - did you just have trouble with the performance, or failed to get the desired output?

Comment: Thanks @user12728748. It never finished for me after 30+ min. I have 16GB ram on a 2 yr old mbp. Interesting that it worked for you.

Comment: Not sure how to explain the difference... memory usage according to profvis was about 12.8GB, so you may still avoid swapping. On a 2011 i7-3930k under linux, R 3.6.1 it takes me 2.3 minutes (granted, with 64 GB of RAM). I am using openblas, but am not sure if that tasks profits from that.

Comment: much appreciated